# Making a C# WinForm project. How can I add an additional loop with which to fill additional text boxes in TextBoxGroup(s)?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have recently made a C# WinForm calculator project which fills a single 3x4 block of text boxes.
Like so:

[3x4 block of text boxes in the form pluss the input TextBoxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnmbQ.png)

This is the code for that:

```
private void calculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox[][] textBoxOutputGroups = new[]
    {
        new [] { tb_Stress111, tb_Stress112, tb_Stress113, },
        new [] { tb_Stress121, tb_Stress122, tb_Stress123, },
        new [] { tb_Stress131, tb_Stress132, tb_Stress133, },
        new [] { tb_Stress141, tb_Stress142, tb_Stress143, },
    };


    if (TextBox1.Text == "" || TextBox2.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Some textboxes are empty!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    else
    {
        double var1;
        double var2;
        double var3;

        var1 = Convert.ToDouble(TextBox1.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        var2 = Convert.ToDouble(TextBox2.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        if (TextBox3.Text == "")
        {
            var3 = (-0.007 * var1 * 2) + 1.8;
        }

        else
        {
            var3 = Convert.ToDouble(TextBox3.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }

        for (int WP = 0; WP <= 3; WP++)
        {
            var S1 = Math.Pow((var2 - var1) * WP, 2);
            var S2 = Math.Pow(4 + var3, 2);
            var S3 = Math.Pow(var1, 2);

            double[] outputValues = new[]
            {
                S1 * var2 / 3,
                S1 * S3 / WP,
                var3 + var1 * S2 / WP,
            };

            for (int i = 0; i < outputValues.Length; i++)
            {
                 textBoxOutputGroups[WP][i].Text =
                     outputValues[i].ToString(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB"));
            }

         }

    }
}
```

This one should fill up a single group of 12 textboxes.

What I'm trying to do now is to add additional 5 groups of 3x4 text box groups, outputs of which would be filled and modified based on the conditions of the new loops which contain the 'j' variable also a new `tadd` variable would be added.

Something like this:

```
TextBox[][] textBoxOutputGroups = new[]
{
    new [] { tb_Stress111, tb_Stress112, tb_Stress113, },
    new [] { tb_Stress121, tb_Stress122, tb_Stress123, },
    new [] { tb_Stress131, tb_Stress132, tb_Stress133, },
    new [] { tb_Stress141, tb_Stress142, tb_Stress143, },
    new [] { tb_Stress211, tb_Stress212, tb_Stress213, },
    new [] { tb_Stress221, tb_Stress222, tb_Stress223, },
    new [] { tb_Stress231, tb_Stress232, tb_Stress233, },
    new [] { tb_Stress241, tb_Stress242, tb_Stress243, },
    new [] { tb_Stress311, tb_Stress312, tb_Stress313, },
    new [] { tb_Stress321, tb_Stress322, tb_Stress323, },
    new [] { tb_Stress331, tb_Stress332, tb_Stress333, },
    new [] { tb_Stress341, tb_Stress342, tb_Stress343, },
    new [] { tb_Stress411, tb_Stress412, tb_Stress413, },
    new [] { tb_Stress421, tb_Stress422, tb_Stress423, },
    new [] { tb_Stress431, tb_Stress432, tb_Stress433, },
    new [] { tb_Stress441, tb_Stress442, tb_Stress443, },
    new [] { tb_Stress511, tb_Stress512, tb_Stress513, },
    new [] { tb_Stress521, tb_Stress522, tb_Stress523, },
    new [] { tb_Stress531, tb_Stress532, tb_Stress533, },
    new [] { tb_Stress541, tb_Stress542, tb_Stress543, },
    new [] { tb_Stress611, tb_Stress612, tb_Stress613, },
    new [] { tb_Stress621, tb_Stress622, tb_Stress623, },
    new [] { tb_Stress631, tb_Stress632, tb_Stress633, },
    new [] { tb_Stress641, tb_Stress642, tb_Stress643, },
    new [] { tb_Stress711, tb_Stress712, tb_Stress713, },
    new [] { tb_Stress721, tb_Stress722, tb_Stress723, },
    new [] { tb_Stress731, tb_Stress732, tb_Stress733, },
    new [] { tb_Stress741, tb_Stress742, tb_Stress743, },
    new [] { tb_Stress811, tb_Stress812, tb_Stress813, },
    new [] { tb_Stress821, tb_Stress822, tb_Stress823, },
    new [] { tb_Stress831, tb_Stress832, tb_Stress833, },
    new [] { tb_Stress841, tb_Stress842, tb_Stress843, },
    new [] { tb_Stress911, tb_Stress912, tb_Stress913, },
    new [] { tb_Stress921, tb_Stress922, tb_Stress923, },
    new [] { tb_Stress931, tb_Stress932, tb_Stress933, },
    new [] { tb_Stress941, tb_Stress942, tb_Stress943, },
    new [] { tb_Stress1011, tb_Stress1012, tb_Stress1013, },
    new [] { tb_Stress1021, tb_Stress1022, tb_Stress1023, },
    new [] { tb_Stress1031, tb_Stress1032, tb_Stress1033, },
    new [] { tb_Stress1041, tb_Stress1042, tb_Stress1043, },
    new [] { tb_Stress1111, tb_Stress1112, tb_Stress1113, },
    new [] { tb_Stress1121, tb_Stress1122, tb_Stress1123, },
    new [] { tb_Stress1131, tb_Stress1132, tb_Stress1133, },
    new [] { tb_Stress1141, tb_Stress1142, tb_Stress1143, },
    new [] { tb_Stress1211, tb_Stress1212, tb_Stress1213, },
    new [] { tb_Stress1221, tb_Stress1222, tb_Stress1223, },
    new [] { tb_Stress1231, tb_Stress1232, tb_Stress1233, },
    new [] { tb_Stress1241, tb_Stress1242, tb_Stress1243, },
};


if (tb_AorticInnerRadious.Text == "" || tb_BloodPressureSystolic.Text == "")
{
    MessageBox.Show("Some textboxes are empty!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
else
{
    double var1;
    double var2;
    double var3;

    var1 = Convert.ToDouble(tb_AorticInnerRadious.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    var2 = Convert.ToDouble(tb_BloodPressureSystolic.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    if (tb_AorticWallThickness.Text == "")
    {
        var3 = (-0.007 * var1 * 2) + 1.8;
    }

    else
    {
        var3 = Convert.ToDouble(tb_AorticWallThickness.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
        var tadd = ((1.25 * var3) - var3) / 6;
        
        for(int j = 1; j < 6; j++) 
        { 
            if(j > 1)
            {
                var3 = var3 + (((Math.Abs(7 - j) * (-1)) + 6) * tadd);
            }

            for (int WP = 0; WP <= 3; WP++)
            {
                var S1 = Math.Pow((var2 - var1) * WP, 2);
                var S2 = Math.Pow(4 + var3, 2);
                var S3 = Math.Pow(var1, 2);

                double[] outputValues = new[]
                {
                    S1 * var2 / 3,
                    S1 * S3 / WP,
                    var3 + var1 * S2 / WP,
                };

                for (int i = 0; i < outputValues.Length; i++)
                {
                    textBoxOutputGroups[WP][i].Text =
                        outputValues[i].ToString(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB"));
                }

            }
        }
```

This one above only filled the textboxes from the original textBoxOutputGroups leaving the rest empty.

Unless there are any better options I see no other way to make this work other than adding additional `textBoxOutputGroups` or adding all the new textboxes into the already existing group.

How should i do this?

Comment: Use a ListView or DataGridView to display grids.

Comment: This doesn't help much. Also how would i be able to divide them in to seperate 3x4 grids with their own named rows and colums for the 6 instances that it is supposed to happen? Again the problem is How do I repeat the 3x4 calclulation 5 additional times?

Comment: @kurmi You can divide 3X4 grids in DGV with named rows and columns and have 6 instances of these 3 X 4 grids I do this by not binding my DGV to the database I style the DGV the way I what it to look OR make 6 of the 3 x 4  grids and put them in the DGV

Comment: If your TextBox NAMING convention follows a PATTERN then you can "search for the controls by name" using [Controls.Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find?view=windowsdesktop-7.0).

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach.

Create a custom **UserControl** (I named it `TextBoxesBlock`). That UserControl should represent a single group of 3x4 TextBoxes:

[image]

For each TextBox set a `Tag` property with number of the TextBox (from 1 to 12), e.g.:

[image]

Tag will be used to properly numerate and order controls, to build 2-dimensional 3x4 array of TextBoxes in code-behind. That backing array will be used for calculations (to be exact, foe easy access to concrete TextBox by indexes of "row" (Stress) and "column" (Wall Place)).

Also, in code-behind of that UserControl provide your calculation method. Assuming from your example, calculations depends half on some user input values, half on previous `TextBoxesBlock`, so I decided to use that parameters as method arguments:

**TextBoxesBlock.cs:**

```
public partial class TextBoxesBlock : UserControl
{
    private readonly TextBox[,] _textBoxGroup = new TextBox[3, 4];
    private readonly CultureInfo _enGBCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB");

    public TextBoxesBlock()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Get a list of TextBoxes, ordered by Tag property (Tag should contain TextBox "number")
        var textBoxes = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().OrderBy(tb => int.Parse(tb.Tag?.ToString())).ToList();
        var textBoxIndex = 0;
        // Fill backing array of TextBoxes with rerefences to TextBoxes on Form
        for (var wallPlace = 0; wallPlace < 4; wallPlace++)
            for (var stress = 0; stress < 3; stress++)
            {
                _textBoxGroup[stress, wallPlace] = textBoxes[textBoxIndex];
                textBoxIndex++;
            }
    }

    public void Calculate(int j, double var1, double var2, double var3)
    {
        if (j > 1)
        {
            var tadd = ((1.25 * var3) - var3) / 6;
            var3 += ((Math.Abs(7 - j) * -1) + 6) * tadd;
        }

        for (int wallPlace = 0; wallPlace < 4; wallPlace++)
        {
            var stressX1 = Math.Pow((var2 - var1) * wallPlace, 2);
            var stressX2 = Math.Pow(4 + var3, 2);
            var stressX3 = Math.Pow(var1, 2);

            var stressValues = new[]
            {
                stressX1 * var2 / 3,
                stressX1 * stressX3 / wallPlace,
                var3 + var1 * stressX2 / wallPlace
            };

            for (int stress = 0; stress < stressValues.Length; stress++)
                _textBoxGroup[stress, wallPlace].Text = stressValues[stress].ToString(_enGBCulture);
        }
    }
}
```

In another Form I added **FlowLayoutPanel** (`flp1` below), which would contain that `TextBoxesBlock`s, and added 6 of them to it:

```cs
public MainForm
{
    InitializeComponent();
    // ...
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        flp1.Controls.Add(new TextBoxesBlock());

    // ...
}
```

And finally, in Button handler you just receiving that `TextBoxesBlock`s list from FlowLayoutPanel and iterating with call of `Calculate` method on each and providing necessary parameters (arguments). As you don't provide initial values for `var1`, `var2` and `var3`, I've put for all just **1**:

```
private void calculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //if (TextBox1.Text == "" || TextBox2.Text == "")
    //{
    //    MessageBox.Show("Some textboxes are empty!", ...);
    //    return;
    //}

    double var1;
    double var2;
    double var3;

    //var1 = Convert.ToDouble(TextBox1.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    //var2 = Convert.ToDouble(TextBox2.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    //if (TextBox3.Text == "")
    //    var3 = (-0.007 * var1 * 2) + 1.8;
    //else
    //    var3 = Convert.ToDouble(TextBox3.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    var blocks = flp1.Controls.OfType<TextBoxesBlock>().ToList();

    for (var j = 0; j < blocks.Count; j++)
    {
        var textBoxesBlock = blocks[j];
        textBoxesBlock.Calculate(j + 1, 1, 1, 1);
    }
}
```

At result I get:

[image]

Maybe not a "ready-to-copy" solution, but I hope you'll get the idea.

Comment: I don't think i do get it. Are all of your code blocks in the same form/class? Also I have updated the question a bit the picture should have the three user inputs which are represented by the TextBox1, 2 and 3 and you should also see a little bit of the 'Calculate' button the fiunctions of which you can see in MY code blocks as the "private void calculate_Click".

Comment: They not in same class. `TextBoxesBlock` is separate UserControl with `Calculate` method. I use it in separate Form (`MainForm`), where added FlowLayoutPanel, which contains a bunch of `TextBoxesBlock`s (UserControls). And in Form i iterate each of `TextBoxesBlock` to perform calculation. Dunno how simplify it more)

Comment: Excuse me everyone for posting code as screenshot. Need just visual explanation. See: `TextBoxesBlock` https://i.stack.imgur.com/FM8vB.png and `MainForm` https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaNKh.png

Comment: Where is the method that activates when i press the Calculate button which you should be able to see in the updated new picture? ("private void calculate_Click")

Comment: @kurmi, supposed to be in `MainForm`. I don't create button in example, just put inside form constructor

Comment: I think I'm missing something. I'm getting at ´MainForm´ that ' The name flp1 doesn't exist in the current context' in the 2 instances that it is present and that 'blocks is not null here' in the for loop. I had hoped that the buttons, input textboxes and output textboxes would be in a single form. I guess there is no helping that.

Comment: `flp1` is FlowLayoutPanel control in MainForm. It should be added from Toolbox in form designer. Place 6x12 TextBoxes in single Form looks horrible, that why I suggest move group of 12 TextBoxes into UserControl. Look again at screenshot of MainForm, there is selected FlowLayoutPanel and it covers whole form.

Comment: I can't rewrite whole program for you) You supposed to catch the idea and adapt it to your project) Idea is simple: group of 12 TextBoxes is 1 single element on form. Each group has its own `Calculate` method which accepts some incoming parameters and sets value to proper TextBoxes in group. In another form you manipulating not over TextBoxes, but over groups, by providing parameters to `Calculate` method for each group in `for` loop. Each group of TextBoxes added into form to a container, like FlowLayoutPanel.

Comment: OK I undestand. Feels like this is going over my head. Still thank you for the response. One more thing. What you might have missed and what i didn't point out properly was the fact that I have already programed the 60 new textboxes to my form they are already present. I just need a way to fill those textboxes.

Comment: If you have already placed them all on the form, and they have a predictable naming pattern, then use `Controls.Find()` as in [this previous example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64640238/2330053).

Comment: Well the naming pattern goes essentially Stress111. The numbers represent: The group number 1-6, Wall Place 1-4 and stess in three stress values 1-3. For example from tb_Stress113 the next one is tb_Stress121. From tb_Stress443 we would jump to tb_Stress511.

Comment: @kurmi you should really deal with UserControl. You bounding your own hands by bounding to specific-named TextBox (and, actually, not single one). Not lefting a chance for yourself and your program to extend or being flexible. As I said, you should take a "base"/"concept" from an answer, and just adapt to your project, fix some lines of code if needed. But you ignore it, continuting your initial flow at which you stuck.

Comment: Well I'm unable to do so. UserControl is entirely new concept to me. I am unable to work with this concept because i don't get it I don't know what I'm supposed to fix. Still thanks for your effort. I had personally hoped that there would have been a simpler fix for this but that doesn't seem to be the case and I'm on the clock

Comment: Edited the code second code block "slightly". This is where I stand with my original creation.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that making a UserControl to represent each 3x4 block makes way more sense, but you've indicated that you want to keep the current setup.

With that in mind, you can get each TextBox by searching for it "by name" with `Controls.Find()` and the recursive search option.

It boils down to this:

```
String group = "4";
String wall = "3";
String stress = "1";
String ctlName = "tb_Stress" + group + wall + stress;
Control[] ctls = this.Controls.Find(ctlName, true);
if (ctls.Length > 0 && ctls[0] is TextBox)
{
    TextBox tb = (TextBox)ctls[0];
    // .. do something with "tb" ...
    tb.Text = "hello!";
}
```

Note that your current naming convention can lead to the wrong TextBox if you enter in the double digits for your groups.

To fix that, you could either use leading zeroes in your numbers, or separate them with another character such as `.` or `_`:

```
tb_Stress040301

tb_Stress.4.3.1

tb_Stress_4_3_1
```